# Rendering Multiline text value (JSON Format) which has Email ID Values in JS Link

Tags: jslink, multiline-text-field

we need to create a JSLink with multiline text value (Stored as JSON) with values seperated in three different columns

sample schema for MultiLine Column:

```
[{"email":"John@xyz.com", "skypeid":"testing", "adgroupname":"test1"},{"email":"John1@xyz.com", "skypeid":"testing11", "adgroupname":"test111"}]
```

if we try to get the value of email using

**ctx.ListData.Row[0].MultilineJSON.replace(/"/g,'"')**

we get output as below

```
"[{"email":"<a href="mailto:John@xyz.com">John@xyz.com</a>", "skypeid":"testing", "adgroupname":"test1"},{"email":"<a href="mailto:John1@xyz.com">John1@xyz.com</a>", "skypeid":"testing11", "adgroupname":"test111"}]"
```

we need to eliminate anchor  tag in the output

how can we achieve this?

any help would be appreciated

Comment: How about using `ctx.CurrentItem["MultilineJSON"]`. Try this and check what are you getting from this? This Multiline text field is Plain or Rich text field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do it with two regexes, one for the start of the tag and one for the end of the tag:

```
var fieldValueString = ctx.ListData.Row[0].MultilineJSON.replace(/"/g,'"');

var regex1 = new RegExp('<a href="mailto.+?">', 'g');
var regex2 = new RegExp('<\/a>', 'g');
fieldValueString = fieldValueString.replace(regex1, '');
fieldValueString = fieldValueString.replace(regex2, '');
var fieldValueJSON = JSON.parse(fieldValueString);
```

---

As requested in comments, some further resources for learning about regular expressions:

The [Regular Expressions guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) on MDN

My preferred online regex tester/playground: [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/)

And of course, you can find so much more with a simple search for "regex" or "regular expressions".

Comment: Thanks this worked like charms..

Comment: Further for learning purpose where can i find more about Regular expressions

Comment: @Pradeep updated my answer